# Problem with old Xeth wallet syncing up

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, wallets

I've got some ETH on an old XETH wallet from 5 years or so and I've never been able to retrieve it.  The ETH doesn't show up in the wallet and the sync bar is completely blank. Based on another troubleshooting guide, I downloaded Geth to update the blockchain. It seemed to be up to the latest block after last night so I opened the XETH wallet but I still don't see any change in the syncing.

EDIT - on Windows 10 - version 0.4-2 (BETA)  There is actually a sliver of a column on the left side of the sync bar

EDIT - Not sure if the Geth has completed.  It says INFO  processed 49,027,060, pending 38,568.  Although when it shows another line for the block it seems to be on the latest block.  Not sure if this is another "layer" it has to go through to reach the latest block on the INFO lines as well?

Thanks

Comment: In their github repo github.com/Xeth/Xeth/ they state that the wallet is no longer maintained. If you have the keystore files you should be able to use other wallet like Metamask, MyEtherWallet, MyCrypt.

Comment: Ismael, it seemed to never generate any keys when I set it up.  I have the password, but no record of any keys.  Could someone locate those based on my receiving address?  I'm at a loss and I would really like to retrieve the ETH now that the price has really gone up

Comment: From github.com/Xeth/Xeth/issues/52 it appears to be standard geth keystore directory.

Comment: Ismael, is there any way I can email you directly for some support on this?  I'm willing to pay you if you can help me retrieve this.  I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about xeth only what is published in their repo.

Comment: Ismael, do you know anyone here who could help me?  I'm just not very technical so I'm wondering if I'm missing something that could make for a simple remedy to this.  I hate to lose that ETH.  Thanks

Comment: Try asking in their github repo, or on reddit.com/r/ethereum if someone knows. Just be careful that someone might try to take advantage of you.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll try reddit.  I think I already asked in the xeth area but it was on older tickets.